# PHP switch statement with same value in multiple cases

Tags: php, switch-statement

I really like the structure of the switch statement compared to using multiple if else.
However some times I want to use the switch statement and have the same value in multiple cases. Can this be done somehow?

```
switch($fruit) {
  case 'apple':
  case 'orange':
    // do something for both apples and oranges
    break;

  case: 'apple':
    // do something for only apples
    break;

  case: 'orange':
    // do something for only oranges
    break;
}
```

I hope my example show what I intend to do...

Comment: @tastro he just wants a case that will run if its apple OR orange, and then a case that will run for each individually.

Comment: The only way I can think of this is multiple switches, one for the ORs, and one for the Singulars

Comment: Other than nesting another `switch` inside the first one to address each special case, you would just need an `if()` inside it.

Comment: You could use the switch(true) functionality for the switch style layout. http://programmersnotes.info/2009/03/06/trick-with-php-switch/

Comment: @t3chguy can you elaborate on this in relation to my example?

Comment: @t3chguy Doesn't really help in this case. You'd need `case $fruit == 'apple' || $fruit == 'orange':`, and then you'd still need another nested `if` or `switch`.

Comment: oh yeah, long day at work -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot. The first `case` that matches and everything following it until the first `break` statement or the end of the `switch` statement will be executed. If you `break`, you break out of the `switch` statement and cannot re-enter it. The best you could do is:

```
switch ($fruit) {
    case 'apple':
    case 'orange':
        ...

        switch ($fruit) {
            case 'apple':
                ...
            case 'orange':
                ...
        }
}
```

But really, don't. If you need some special action for those two before the individual `switch`, do an `if (in_array($fruit, ['apple', 'orange'])) ...` before the `switch`. Or rethink your entire program logic and structure to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Create some function and do it like this:

```
switch($fruit) {

  case: 'apple':
    apple_and_orange_function();
    apple_function();
    break;

  case: 'orange':
    apple_and_orange_function();
    orange_function();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match something multiple times, but you can write cascades like these:

```
switch($fruit) {
  case 'apple':
    // do something for only apples
  case 'orange':
    // do something for both apples and oranges
    break;
  case: 'grapefruit':
    // do something for only grapefruits
    break;
}
```

What you want can only be performed with if-else's or deceze's solution though